# How to mouse over an web element to see a list of hidden option then process to click those options? - Selenium ChromeDriver - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to learn Excel VBA for automation testing using chrome browser.

- Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Selenium Basic 2.0.9
- Chrome Driver 2.4.5

I'm stuck at the point where I need to hover on a web element for showing it's options then process to click that option.
The problem here is you need to hover on the parent element so that it will trigger javascript for adding new html to show child-element which is needed for clicking but I can't afford to perform mouse hover action code.

I'm using this site for testing: http://lienminh360.vn/.

Here is my code for now - won't work though

```
Sub Button10_Click()

    Dim driver As WebDriver
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver

    driver.Start "chrome"
    driver.Window.SetPosition 0, 0
    driver.Window.SetSize 1000, 1000
    driver.Get "http://lienminh360.vn/"

    driver.Wait 3000
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id ='menu-item-33']").AsSelect.SelectByIndex (3)
    driver.Wait 3000
    driver.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try click and hold. It would help if you explained what selections you expected to see. The element you are targeting is a `li` element and so the syntax you are using is wrong. It is designed for a parent `select` element. If that is the correct element I am targeting you can remove the click and hold line altogether and just use the click on the target. The element is not javascript rendered post load.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeSelection()
    Dim driver As WebDriver
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver

    driver.Start "chrome"
    driver.Window.SetPosition 0, 0
    driver.Window.SetSize 1000, 1000
    driver.Get "http://lienminh360.vn/"
    'driver.FindElementById("menu-main-menu").ClickAndHold
    driver.FindElementById("menu-item-33").Click

    Stop

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, I used ClickAndHold and it works. Thank you male. @QHarr 
  ```driver.FindElementById("menu-item-33").ClickAndHold driver.Wait 3000 driver.FindElementById("menu-item-36").Click```